# Rails and Capistrano missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with missed gems when i tried to deploy rails app to vps. Can you help me?

**capistrano.log**

```html
bundle check --path /home/root/apps/appname/shared/bundle
DEBUG [09094abf]  [31mThe following gems are missing[0m
[31m * net-scp (1.2.1)[0m
[31m * sshkit (1.11.4)[0m
[31m * airbrussh (1.1.1)[0m
[31m * debug_inspector (0.0.2)[0m
[31m * binding_of_caller (0.7.2)[0m
[31m * byebug (9.0.6)[0m
[31m * capistrano-harrow (0.5.3)[0m
[31m * capistrano (3.6.1)[0m
[31m * capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)[0m
[31m * capistrano-rails (1.2.0)[0m
[31m * capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)[0m
[31m * capistrano3-puma (1.2.1)[0m
[31m * spring (2.0.0)[0m
[31m * web-console (2.3.0)[0m
[33mInstall missing gems with `bundle install`
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [capistrano/bundler](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler) gem to get the bundler tasks (like `bundle install`) in your deploy.

Basically, you must add the `capistrano/bundler` in your Gemfile and require it in your Capfile using the command below:

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
```

Thereby the Capistrano will run the `bundle install` task during the deploy and this problem will be solved.